# Simple 301 RedirectMatch with URL input variables not working

Tags: apache-2.2, 301-redirect

I have this line in my .htaccess and the 301 redirect is not working. It just doesn't redirect. Can anybody see anything wrong with this? Keep in mind, I have 7 other RedirectMatch strings in my .htaccess and they all work fine.

I am trying to redirect a query like:

```
mydomain.com/?start=4
```

to

```
mydomain.com/index.php?start=4
```

Using this in my .htaccess

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/?start=(.*)$ http://mydomain.com/index.php?start=$1
```

Comment: Did you reload apache?